# Send SMS After RasDial

Tags: c++, winapi, serial-port, ras

I'm developing a small 3G connection manager under Windows using C++ and I can't understand how to send an SMS once a 3G connection is established via RasDial.

I have code to access a serial port and I understand the AT commands to send an SMS. This works fine if I can open the serial port. However, after a RasDial call, opening the serial port with CreateFile fails, as RAS seems to have exclusive access to it.

Has anyone an idea how other connection managers manage to get around this?

Comment: A little further research done and I see how it is done for Huawei devices. It seems there are two available COM ports. RAS uses one of them and the other usually named "HUAWEI Mobile Connect - 3G PC UI Interface" can be used for SMS.

Comment: I think you can check if there's a linux perl script for sending SMS from this device